# Como incluir GAM en Genexus Evo 3

Tags: genexus, devices

Como incluir GAM en una Aplicación desarrollada con Genexus Evo 3

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow Marcelo, de preferencia hay que desarrollar más la pregunta, por ejemplo escribiendo que cosas has tratado anteriormente. Saludos

Comment: Eleansys, considero que la pegunta es correcta, precisa y concreta. La respuesta que figura más abajo es de gran utilidad y describe la configuración solicitada.

Comment: @jcnina del [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26003372#26003372): Me parece que la pregunta carece de evidencia de esfuerzo de investigación. Creo que una pregunta concisa y concreta debe al menos indicar la documentación y palabras clave de búsqueda utilizadas para googlearlo (o el símil en cualquier otro buscador) como evidencia de esfuerzo de resolverlo por uno mismo...

Comment: Por otro lado, si se publica para documentar una solución encontrada por uno mismo debería incluirse algo del contexto que señale su relevancia además de que ser autorespondida al momento de publicar la pregunta.

Comment: Cabe agregar las "malas preguntas" con "excelentes respuestas" son una buena oportunidad para la [medalla de reversión](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/57/reversal)

Comment: Me parece que la percepción de esta pregunta puede variar mucho si se conocen las tecnologías involucradas. Para mí no es precisa, pero si cambiase (por ejemplo) GAM por un plugin y la app en Genexus por un IDE el contenido sería suficiente. Voto por reabrir, porque técnicamente me parece válida, pero personalmente estaría menos inclinado a contestar una pregunta tan escueta debido a una _aparente_ falta de detalles o esfuerzo en explicar el contexto y el problema.

Answer (score 9):

Para habilitar GAM, tienes que configurar la propiedad `Enable Integrated Security` en su valor `True`. (Es una propiedad a nivel de versión de tu base de conocimiento (KB)).

Esto te permitirá resolver automáticamente la seguridad de tu aplicación. Podrás administrar usuarios, roles y permisos para controlar el acceso a tu aplicación (autenticación) y también resolver los permisos de acceso a tus programas (autorización).

Se importará el API del GAM, y opcionalmente paneles que ya la utilizan y permiten administrar el GAM y dar opciones básicas de login, registración, etc.

Dado que mencionas que lo quieres agregar a una aplicación ya desarrollada, también debes, luego de habilitar el GAM, también comenzar a ver en qué partes de la aplicación vas a requerir autenticación y cuáles no; si deseas que GAM maneje permisos o solo autenticación y más cosas que dependerán de tu aplicación.
Sugiero comenzar la lectura desde [aquí](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?19888).